# Move png's with CSS

Tags: html, css, pull

How can I put the arrow in the button box? Any suggestions about the code would be appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<!--Header-->
<div class="mainHeader header">
    <h1>
        LET US MAKE YOUR AWESOME IDEA HAPPENN
    </h1>
    <div class="button">
        <p class="">
            WATCH VIDEO
        </p><img src="playbutton.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.button {
    width: 250px;
    height: 46px;
    border: solid white 2px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    top: 70%;
}
.button p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPpQPV

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  background: #000;
}

button {
  width: 250px;
  height: 46px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: none;
  border: solid white 2px;  
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;  
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
  color: white;    
}
```

```html
<button>
         WATCH SHOWREEL 
        <img src="http://iconizer.net/files/Splashyfish/orig/arrow_medium_down.png">
      </button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how can I position it below the h1 now ? I did it with relative position and %'s but its not working now for some reason ?